# SQL Consulta a DB count

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada decreto en la base de datos con los siguientes campos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y deseo ver los años que tengo en mi base de datos en que he ingresado datos. Ejemplo en la base de datos he ingresado fechas el 2016 2017 2018 y la query que me muestre los valores 2018 - 2017 - 2016.
Tengo la siguiente query pero no funciona muy bien.

```html
SELECT fecha
    FROM decreto
    WHERE fecha
    IN (
    SELECT fecha
    FROM decreto
    GROUP BY fecha
    HAVING count( fecha ) >1
    )
    ORDER BY fecha
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero poder explicarme bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu problema es que el orden no es correcto, el problema es que por defecto mysql ordena de forma ascendente los resultados, solo debes añadir DESC al final de la consulta, de esta forma:

```
SELECT fecha
    FROM decreto
    WHERE fecha
    IN (
    SELECT fecha
    FROM decreto
    GROUP BY fecha
    HAVING count( fecha ) >1
    )
    ORDER BY fecha DESC;
```

Edit: Para que muestre las fechas sin duplicados basta con añadir un Distinct de la fecha, la consulta quedaria más o menos así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(fecha)
    FROM decreto
    WHERE fecha
    IN (
    SELECT fecha
    FROM decreto
    GROUP BY fecha
    HAVING count( fecha ) >1
    )
    ORDER BY fecha DESC;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me funciona con el tema del orden pero lo que ocurre que me muestra duplicado los años. Solo quiero que me muestre 2018 2017 2016 No 2018 2018 2017 2017 2017 2016.

Comment: Edito la respuesta para contestar a tu pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona excelentemente te lo agradezco mucho :). Gracias por tu tiempo saludos cordiales.

Comment: ya ha pasado tiempo pero en esa query puedo contar cuantas veces en un año he ingreso data

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer 
SELECT UNIQUE fecha
FROM decreto
WHERE fecha IS NOT NULL;